# using php variables outside of a loop, that contain query results

Tags: php, variables

I have a PHP loop that contains a query within the loop I set two variables to contain certain results, I then want to use the variables outside of the loop. However when I do they just return as undefined. The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$standardresult = mssql_query("SELECT Price FROM Extras WHERE ExtraID = 5 ");

while ($standardrow = mssql_fetch_array($standardresult )) { 
    $toughresult = mssql_query("SELECT Price FROM Extras WHERE ExtraID = 6 ");

    while ($toughrow = mssql_fetch_array($toughresult)) {
        $toughprice = $toughrow['Price'];
        $standardprice = $standardrow['Price'];
        echo $standardrow['Price'];
        echo $toughrow['Price'];
        ?>

        <td align="center">
            <input type="radio" name="triple" value="yes" onclick="showPrice('<?php echo $standardrow['Price']; ?>','<?php echo $toughrow['Price']; ?>')" /> yes
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="radio" name="triple" value="no" onclick="showPrice('0','0')" checked="checked" /> no
        </td>

        <?php 
    } 
} 
?>

</tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" name="ToughPrice" value="<?php echo $toughprice; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="StanPrice" value="<?php echo $standardprice; ?>" />
```

the variables in question are $toughprice and $standardprice. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, or if its possible please? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please indent your code properly...

Comment: Sorry, tried to but you had already edited it. :/ Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$standardresult = mssql_query("SELECT Price FROM Extras WHERE ExtraID = 5 ");
while ($standardrow = mssql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$toughresult = mssql_query("SELECT Price FROM Extras WHERE ExtraID = 6 ");
while ($toughrow = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

??? i guess it should be

```
$standardresult = mssql_query("SELECT Price FROM Extras WHERE ExtraID = 5 ");
while ($standardrow = mssql_fetch_array($standardresult)) { 

$toughresult = mssql_query("SELECT Price FROM Extras WHERE ExtraID = 6 ");
while ($toughrow = mssql_fetch_array($toughresult)) {
```

maybe it will make a difference ...

Comment: was a silly error on my part, thank you for pointing it out, however was just a typo when I writ the code, so the issue still stands. +1 though :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any other output besides the  tags with value undefined?
If not, one of your queries did not return results and you never defined the variables outside your while statements.

In java you would even get syntax errors for this approach as it is not robust what you are doing here.
What do you expect in the variables after your final while statement has been executed? Only the last entry out of the possible entry sets you received via query?
If you do not expect more than one row, you do not need the WHILE and just fetch the first result. I do not know the MSSQL statement for "LIMIT 1" - but this could also help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite ok, but you made logic mistake - you got `while` loop this **ends** if tehre's no more data to assign to your `$toughresult`. So once loop ends, `$toughresult` does not contain any usable data:

> Returns a MS SQL result resource on success, TRUE if no rows were
>   returned, or FALSE on error.

So just do `var_dump($toughresult);` to verify this. If you want to use your data, either break the loop or copy your data to another variable which will not be overwritten.

To avoid such issues in future, always ensure you checked manual for possible return values and make sure your code handles it right, incl. edge cases.

Comment: The question isn't about `$toughresult` it's about `$toughprice`. It should contain the value from the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`undefined` means that the variable used isn't initialized. That would be true for your  `$toughprice` and `$standardprice` if the code never went through your second `while` loop. This could be obvious from the rendered html on your page because the on-the-fly created `html` (`td`s in this case ) should not be created.

From your code this would be the case when:

1. The first query doesn't return any result or
2. The first query did returned some result but the second query didn't.

So debug those queries to see what's wrong.

PS: I'm not sure why you're using two nested `while` loops which the internal doesn't need data from the external. You have two static queries which could be independent of each other. If for some reason you need for each item of the first loop to iterate over the results of the second loop do it *after* you perform the database queries. Now you 're getting the *same* results for the second query N times (N are the rows for the first query)

Finally if for some reason not having any results is an expected scenario, then initialize your variables *before* the `while` loops in order to get rid of `undefined` errors

For example:

```
<?php  
$toughprice = 0; // default value
$standardprice = 0; //default value

... 
while (...) {  
    while (...) { 
        $toughprice = ...        
        $standardprice = ... 
    }
}
...

<input type="hidden" name="ToughPrice" value="<?php echo $toughprice; ?>" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="StanPrice" value="<?php echo $standardprice; ?>" />
```